# Wordpress deletes settings if they are on multiple admin pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I created plugin which contains two admin pages. When I change and save settings on one admin page, wordpress deletes settings from the other.

I register settings

```
register_setting( SETTINGS_GROUP, SETTING_1);
register_setting( SETTINGS_GROUP, SETTING_2);
```

And each page has form with inputs

```
<form class="roles-settings" action="options.php" method="post">
<?php settings_fields( SETTINGS_GROUP ); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections( SETTINGS_GROUP ); ?>
...inputs...
</form>
```

I solved it with pre_update_option hook (please see below), but I think that this is not the way how to handle things.

```
function update_option($newValue, $oldValue) {
    if ($newValue == null) {
        return $oldValue;
    }
    return $newValue;
}
add_filter('pre_update_option_'. SETTING_1, 'update_option', 10, 2);
add_filter('pre_update_option_'. SETTING_2, 'update_option', 10, 2);
```

I think that I saw this behaviour for a first time when I updated to Wordpress 4.7.1

Is there any more "natural" way how to solve this?